# how to add an image icon to my openerp custom module

Tags: odoo

Hi I have made a custom module for my openerp-7 . Now I need to include an image icon as the other modules but I am lacking the setting to do this . What changes should I have to made to have this icon view available.

Hopes for suggesstion
Regards

Answer (score 0):

save your icon as 'icon.png' and place it under `your_module_directory/static/src/img`
for example check account_voucher module. Its icon images path  is in account_voucher/static/src/img/icon.png

Openerp will automatically selects the icon from the static/src/img path

Answer (score 0):

for creating an icon to the custom module you have to override your default icon that exists in the base module

```
base/static/description/icon.png.
```

write your icon in the description folder.

```
your project name /static/description/icon.png.
```

I think this will help you to change the icon.